# Testing Spring Retry Circuit Breaker

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-retry, circuit-breaker

I am using Spring Retry Circuit Breaker in one of my Spring Boot applications as:

```
   @CircuitBreaker(include = CustomException.class, maxAttempts = 3, openTimeout = 2000L, resetTimeout = 4000L)
StudentResponse getStudentInfo(String studentId) {
    StudentResponse res = studentRepository.getInfoByStudentId(studentId);
    return res;
}

@Recover
StudentResponse recoverStudentInfo(CustomException ex, String studentId) {
    throw new StudentApiException("In recovery...");
}
```

Now I'm trying to test it using Junit 5 as:

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @EnableRetry
    public class StudentServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @MockBean
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void testCircuitBreakGetStudentInfo(){
        String id = "id";
        doThrow(CustomException.class).when(studentRepository).getInfoByStudentId(id);
        StudentResponse res = this.studentService.getStudentInfo(id);
        verify(studentRepository, times(3)).getInfoByStudentId(id); // this is telling that there has been 1 interaction with the mock

    }
}
```

Then I tried:

```
 @Test
    public void testCircuitBreakGetStudentInfo(){
        String id = "id";
        doThrow(CustomException.class).when(studentRepository).getInfoByStudentId(id);
        assertThrows(StudentApiException.class,
            ()->{ this.studentService.getStudentInfo(id); }); // this is also telling that there has been 1 interaction with the mock instead of 3
    }
```

Shouldn't there be 3 interactions? Or will it be one? Any explanation will be of great help. Any other tips on testing the circuit breaker is appreciated (I could hardly find any example on testing this circuit breaker). Thanks